# Using SSL from Java on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and I don't seem to have enough entropy for generating random numbers in SSL.

I tried using both `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` but that didn't make a big difference: starting my HTTPS server takes minutes as well as generating a seed for any incoming connection.

What's the solution to a lack of entropy ?

Comment: Are you sure it's lack of entropy? If it was using `/dev/urandom` (which ignores lack of entropy) should change something.

Comment: I tried to create a SecureRandom and log it at startup: it is of type SHA1PRNG. Still, when initializing the SSL engine and generating a first random seed, the operation takes several minutes

Comment: Can you post code some code to show the issue?  I'm hosted on an EC2 and, while I have Apache handling my SSL I've never seen any issues like you're describing.  Are you just trying to create the SSL listen socket?

Comment: I am launching the socket as a part of an http app based on Akka Http. The code hangs for hours here: trigger seeding of SecureRandom